# Using jQuery to change the value of class inside the DOM

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the value of a class inside the DOM

I currently have this:

```
<span class="something">VALUE1</span>
```

From a drop down menu, I can change it VALUE2. When I inspect the DOM, I notice that it changes to:

```
<span class="something">VALUE2</span>
```

I know I should be using `.attr()`, but the documentation I've seen is to change the class. How do I use `.attr()` to change the value?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post a complete code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the name of your class

```
$(".something").attr('class', 'something2');
```

This will change the value within the `<span>` tag

```
$(".something").html('Value3');
```

Comment: That worked, but when I refresh the page, it reverts back to VALUE1. I understand it's changing the value inside the DOM, but it's not sending it back to the server. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I went about it a different way, but got it to work!

Comment: You cannot use a span object to post values. You need to use input to post values.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of jQuery's built in `addClass()` and `removeClass()` functions, but to use `attr()` you would do something like this.

**HTML**

Notice the `id` has been added.

`<span id="value1" class="something">Value 1</span>`

Then do something like this:

`$("#value1").attr("class", "theclassyouwant");`

Comment: ahh ok, let me try this!